# How to stop Win11 pro V21H2 update

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I want to disable the update of Win 11 so I follow this steps:

- Run
- services.msc
- Windows update
- Disable

The problem after a period of time it return to manual.
Is there any problem in my instalation steps for win11? or what happen?

Comment: Individual computer users (not Company) with standard Windows (not LTSC) cannot stop updates.  This is particularly true with Windows 11.  Why are you trying to stop the update?